# Does Google EMM API support Enterprise Enrolment via G-Suite Account?

Tags: mdm, android-management-api, emm

I'm trying to enroll in Google Play Services using my G-Suite account, but I keep encountering the error message:
`G Suite is not currently supported by managed Google Play Accounts. Please choose a non-G Suite account to continue.`

I am using below Google EMM API for generagting the signup url

https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/enterprises/generateSignupUrl

Has anyone else faced this issue? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Getting below message

`G Suite is not currently supported by managed Google Play Accounts. Please choose a non-G Suite account to continue.` 
however expectation it should re-direct to google play service page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZImtU.png)